# Should a poor answer be flagged as commentary?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer

This is in relation to the following [Review Task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25067123).

The answer may be of poor formatting quality. It may not even work. However, it does have clear instructions on how to attempt to fix the problem, along with the claim that it did fix the issue for the answerer.

Why is this question flagged as "Commentary not Answer"? It does *attempt* to answer the question. If the answer is wrong, shouldn't it just be downvoted?

Comment: You might have forgotten where you were. The "Late answers" queue has a higher focus on quality of the answer than usual. Also, when you already say "The answer may be of poor formatting quality.", then why did you chose "No action needed" in stead of fixing the poor formatting?

Comment: I don't see why that specific queue should have a different standard for what constitutes an answer. Is it the *quality* of the answer that under scrutiny here or whether or not whatever has been posted *qualifies* as an answer (however bad)? Because I have also been on the other end when I flagged or voted to close a single-line answer and was rejected for "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies"

Comment: And I say poor formatting but that's a stretch. It's just a one-line seemingly self-sufficient answer, I didn't think it needed any improvements

Comment: That answer has missing formatting for the command, at least two typos and missing punctuation. Still, no action needed is incorrect there. And if an answer "comes late to the party", then it should add something new to it, that is why the late answer queue expects more checks from the reviewer.

Comment: Ok, I can understand the action needed part. I still wish there was some form of consistency between when to flag or downvote. I feel like I have been on both wrong ends. Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: Regarding downvotes: that doesn't need to change. There are certain reasons one can downvote (hover to down arrow to see them), but you can still apply your own rules and be more lenient or restrictive there.

Comment: FWIW, First Post and Late Answer are always flagged by the system automatically following certain criteria. No human users can flag a post to make it into First Post or Late Answer.